# render() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) in Django error

Tags: python, django

```
form1 = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
print form1
context = {"form1": form1.render(paypal_dict['amount']),}
print context
return render_to_response('choose_plan.html',context)
```

This sends the context to the html but it is showing up this error now.

```
render() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I'm completely confused as to why.

Comment: Why are you calling that render method at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because render is a function in the object `form1`, and expects only the `self` argument. Since you pass an argument to the function in your call that becomes the *second* argument.